# Angular 2 radio button ngmodel

Tags: angular6, angular5, angular2-forms

Radio button validation not working properly in angular 2. I tried but i do not know how to use ng-model.Anyone can resolve this issue?

```
  <div *ngIf="f.submitted && radio.invalid">
 Please check any one
 </div>

   <form #f="ngForm">
<div *ngFor="let option of options">
    <div class="radio">
        <input type="radio"
           name="radio"
           id="radio-{{option.id}}"
           [(ngModel)]="value"
           [value]="option.value"
           #radio="ngModel"
           />

    <label for="radio-{{option.id}}">{{option.id}}
    </label>

 </div>
 </div>
 <button>Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: check https://plnkr.co/edit/ufRNSFV9EYeBmyItaF6Q?p=preview

Comment: Check..that concept not working